# WPF deforms opacity mask

Tags: wpf, mask

I'm trying to achieve this:

[image]

The gradient proportion will grow so I did a circle as opacityMask then a recangle using the circle as mask, like that:

```
<Ellipse Name="Mask" 
    Fill="Red" 
    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=mainGrid}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
    Visibility="Visible"/>
    
<Rectangle Name="Gradient" Fill="Azure" 
   Grid.Column="2" Width="100" 
   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
   VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
   <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Mask}" />
   </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
</Rectangle>
```

and I get this:
[image]

How do I keep the rectangle's form and mask it using the circle ??

Comment: As a note, something like `Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=mainGrid}"` is *never* necessary. A Grid does already set the size of its child elements according to the related property settings.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Mask}"
             Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need something like this:

```
    <Border Name="Mask"
            Background="White"
            Grid.Column="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    </Border>
    
    <Ellipse Name="gradient" 
             Stroke="Black"
             StrokeThickness="1"
             Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=mainGrid}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
             Visibility="Visible">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0" > >
                <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
        <Ellipse.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Mask}"  
                         Stretch="None"
                         AlignmentX="Right"
                         AlignmentY="Top" />
        </Ellipse.OpacityMask>
    </Ellipse>

    <Border Name="Mask2"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Background="White"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    </Border>
    <Ellipse Name="BlueEllipse" 
             Fill="Blue" 
             Stroke="Black"
             StrokeThickness="1"
             Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=mainGrid}" 
             Grid.ColumnSpan="3" >
        <Ellipse.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Mask2}" 
                         Stretch="None" 
                         AlignmentX="Left"
                         AlignmentY="Top"/>
        </Ellipse.OpacityMask>
    </Ellipse>
```

To achive what the original image is.

Comment: Wow, that was pretty close but I need the grandient to start in the vertical and change it size that's what I was using a rectangle starting in the 3rd column and with a width of, for instance, 100px. I need it to "grow" dynamically. Size can be fixed and the "grow" can be handled by grandient stops. But should start on the vertical bar